# Google map above every divs

Tags: html, google-maps, position

i'm using the Google map API for my website, i notice that the map goes above the elements of my page, even the popup divs with the "position:absolute". I have tried to change the css position attribute but no success. How can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CSS attribute z-index sets the position of a non-statically positioned element on the z axis.

Try adding this to your div's style:

```
div {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9999999;
}
```